# Tight bounds for average running time of quicksort?

Tags: probability, inequality, algorithms

When analysing the expected running time of the randomized quicksort algorithm, we get the expected number of comparisons made

$$E = \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\sum_{j=2}^{n-i+1}\frac{2}{j} $$
We derive an upper bound to the running time of the algorithm using the inequality

$$E = \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\sum_{j=2}^{n-i+1}\frac{2}{j} \le \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\sum_{j=1}^{n}\frac{2}{j}$$

$$\le \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\log(n) \le n\log(n)$$

I was wondering if we can we make this bound tighter? Is there an equality of the first equation with a closed form formula rather than an inequality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have:
$$ E = \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\sum_{j=2}^{n-i+1}\frac{2}{j} = 2\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\left(H_{n-i+1}-1\right)=2\sum_{k=2}^{n}\left(H_k-1\right)=2\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(H_k-1\right)\tag{1} $$
but [summation by parts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation_by_parts) gives:
$$ \sum_{k=1}^{n} 1\cdot H_k = n H_n - \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{k}{k+1} = nH_n-(n-1)+(H_n-1)=(n+1)H_n-n,\tag{2}$$
hence it follows that:

> $$ \color{red}{E} = (2n+2)\,H_n-4n = \color{red}{(2n+2)\log n + (2\gamma-4)n + O(1)} \tag{3} $$
>   by the asymptotics on [harmonic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number).